# Cannot get D3.js to work inside Svelte component (with Rollup)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollupjs, svelte

I've been trying to put the most basic D3 example into a Svelte app and can't get it to work. At first I tried installing D3 as a node module: `npm install d3` but this produces the same result (a lack of result) as importing D3 as an external script from CDN inside of `index.html`: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`. Using either method I get a bunch of circular dependency warnings on app start:

```
(!) Circular dependency: node_modules\d3-selection\src\selection\index.js -> node_modules\d3-selection\src\selection\select.js -> node_modules\d3-selection\src\selection\index.js
```

But the app starts with no errors, and no D3 dynamic formatting occurs, nor any errors pop up in the DevTools console inside Chrome.

The Svelte component looks like this:

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    var data = [30, 86, 168, 281, 303, 365];

    d3.select(".chart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) {
        return d + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
        return d;
        });
</script>

<style>
      .chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<div class="chart"></div>
```

Putting the code above into a static HTML file produces a bar chart, as expected. But when run as a Svelte component nothing is displayed.

My rollup.config.js is:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/bundle.js',
        globals: { 'd3': 'd3' },
        external: [ 'd3' ]
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            dev: !production,
            css: css => { css.write('public/bundle.css'); }
        }),
        resolve({ browser: true }),
        commonjs(),
        !production && livereload('public'),
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

...and index.html is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bundle.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would suspect Rollup not bundling D3 module correctly, but as an external script in `<body>` it should in theory work, but it doesn't. Please point me in the right direction, I've spent way too much time trying to get it to work, and as a JS noob am out of options. Thanks!

Comment: There is a Svelte+D3 example: [link](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-d3-arc-demo) but I still can't see what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `<div class="chart"></div>` element doesn't exist when your code first runs — the contents of `<script>` run when the component is instantiated. If you need to access DOM elements inside the component, it will first be available inside [onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount):

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  // other code...

  onMount(() => {
    d3.select('.chart')
      // ...
  });
</script>
```

Using a selector like `.chart` is dangerous though, because if you had more than one component on the page D3 would select the wrong thing. It's better to use [bind:this](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element) instead:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  // other code...

  let el;

  onMount(() => {
    d3.select(el) // no danger of selecting the wrong element
      // ...
  });
</script>

<div class="chart" bind:this={el}></div>
```

Now all you need to change is the CSS — because Svelte will discard selectors that it thinks are unused, and because it can't know what D3 is going to do, it will remove `.chart div {...}`. Instead, use the [:global(...) modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs#style) to target divs inside your top-level element:

```html
<style>
  .chart :global(div) {
    /* styles */
  }
</style>
```

With those changes, it works perfectly:

https://svelte.dev/repl/8722c32f4e1a44a98e3a3fc8a095b2d7?version=3.5.3

But in this case, D3 isn't really bringing anything to the party. You could achieve the same result much more simply:

```html
<script>
  var data = [30, 86, 168, 281, 303, 365];
</script>

<style>
  .chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<div class="chart">
  {#each data as d}
    <div style="width: {d}px">
      {d}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

As well as being less code for you to write, your app now contains a lot less JavaScript. Demo here: https://svelte.dev/repl/be5cac1695554b8e9ee6d0bc14b9dff1?version=3.5.3

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation! This D3 example was just to test if D3 is working before I start using it in more complex ways. Now that I see it working properly I will code zoomable charts ;) Thanks again!

Comment: is it necessary to include the `d3.v5.min.js` in index.html if you import it from your component? shouldn't it go to bundle.js???

Comment: Any thoughts on getting rid of the circular dependency warning? Thanks!

Comment: @mikemaccana looks like the answer for removing the d3-selection warnings is a no https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/229

Comment: The global modifier still seems to work only if there's a pre-existing element of the same kind. I cannot seem to select elements that are generated with D3. 
Options:
- do the styling in D3 (complicates templating, which is a good advantage of using svelte)
- use loops on svelte, which works for most charts, probably. I'm a bit new to svelte, so I'm not sure if the data reactivity I get from D3 will transfer well. 
- Maybe there is a way to make the styles work?
Thanks in advance to anyone who answers!
-